# Git clone over ssh, push over https

Tags: git, ssh, https, bitbucket

I have a set of private Git repos in BitBucket. I want to clone them through SSH so that the cloning can be automated without asking for a password. However, I want to push over HTTPS because I want to push with a different user name.

The PC is a common PC, and I want to distinguish who pushes changes but I do not care about who clone them.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use two or more different remotes for that. By default, when you clone a remote repository, the remote `origin` is automatically created for you. But you can specify a different repository on the git command line each time literally like e.g.

```
git push https://git-server/myrepo.git branch
```

but it is much more convenient to add them as named remotes if you plan to use them more than once. Here is a more complete example transcript:

```
git clone ssh://user1@git-server/myrepo.git
cd myrepo
git remote add push https://git-server/myrepo.git
```

Then you can `git fetch origin` or `git pull` to update the local checkout, and you can push with e.g. `git push push branch` (Note that the second `push` here is the name of the remote). This way, you can also specify a different ssh remote with a different user:

```
git remote add push2 ssh://user2@git-server/myrepo.git
```

Then you can do `git push push2 branch` in order to push via ssh as a different user.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I actually knew I could do that, but didn't think about it that way :) Just one question regarding adding a second ssh with different user: how does the SSH key work in this case? user2 will be able to push because I have the key assigned to user1? Or does user2 needs to deploy another SSH key? Thanks!!

Comment: The ssh key to be used depends on which ssh keys are known on the server as authorized_keys for the different users. If both users have the same public key in their `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, then the same will work for the client. Otherwise different keys have to be used.